# Segmentation fault due to pointer in gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am trying to implement a linked list using following code, I got segment fault error     please tell me where is the problem.

I'm using ubuntu gcc compiler, please suggest me something

```
#include<iostream>

using  std::cout;
using  std::cin;


class ll
{
    struct node
    {
        int info;
        node *nextnode ;
    }*n;



public:
    ll()
    {
        n=NULL;
    }

    void getinfo()
    { 
        node *temp,*r;


        if( n==NULL )
        {
            temp=new node;
            cout<<" \n enter the first elements of linklist \n";
            int z;
            cin>>z;
            //i guess problem starts here
            temp->info=z;
            cout<<"the value of info is";
            temp->nextnode = NULL;
            n=temp;
        }
        else{
            temp=n;
            cout<<"heheh balls";
            while(temp->nextnode==NULL)
            {
                temp=temp->nextnode;
            }
            r=new node;
            cout<<"enter the element \t";
            int y;
            cin>>y; 
            r->info=y;
            r->nextnode=NULL;
            temp=r;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        node *temp=n;
        while(temp->nextnode==NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->info;

        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    ll p;
    int v;
    cout<<"enter the number of elements to be added to linklist \t";
    cin>>v;
    //tryn to input linklist from terminal
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
    {
        p.getinfo();
    }
    p.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please reformat the code by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl-K`.

Comment: Well, run it in GDB, and you'll be told what line it crashed on, and the values of all variables at the time of the crash.

Comment: thanks OliCharlesworth but where do i get GDB n do i have that in built in g++

Comment: Yes, you'll almost certainly have it installed if you already have GCC.  Just type `gdb my_prog_name` at the command-line, and then type `run` at the prompt.  Learning GDB is essential if you're developing C++ under Linux.

Comment: I see memory leaks and errors, but don't immediately see a segfualt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(temp->nextnode==NULL)
{
    temp=temp->nextnode;
}
....
temp=r;
```

should be

```
while(temp->nextnode!=NULL)
{
    temp=temp->nextnode;
}
....
temp->nextnode=r;
```

Same goes for:

```
void display()
{
    node *temp=n;
    while(temp->nextnode==NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->info;

    }
}
```

should be:

```
void display()
{
    node *temp=n;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->info;
        temp = temp->nextnode;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @KoKoToru can you pls tell what part of code lead to segment fault

Comment: you accessed a 0-point .. because your while's were wrong

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in the code, look below:

```
 void
  getinfo ()
  {
    node *temp, *r;

    if (n == NULL)
      {
    temp = new node;
    cout << " \n enter the first elements of linklist \n";
    int z;
    cin >> z;
    //i guess problem starts here
    temp->info = z;
    cout << "the value of info is";
    temp->nextnode = NULL;
```

The next line is added, you have to point the head at the first element.

```
    n = temp;
```

continuing ...

```
      }
    else
      {
    temp = n;
    cout << "heheh balls";
```

Here you should iterate while here **is** a next element, changed `==` to `!=`.

```
    while (temp->nextnode != NULL)
```

continuing ...

```
      {
        temp = temp->nextnode;
      }
    r = new node;
    cout << "enter the element \t";
    int
      y;
    cin >> y;
    r->info = y;
    r->nextnode = NULL;
    temp->nextnode  = r;
      }
  }
```

Next function:

```
  void
  display ()
  {
    node *temp = n;
```

The next line changed, keep printing numbers while you have a node

```
while (temp)
  {
    cout << temp->info;
```

And don't forget to move to the next node

```
        temp = temp->nextnode;
      }
  }
```

And that's it, it works.

Comment: Thanks Chill but i have a doubt regarding statement "temp=new node;" when we have declared node * temp ; what is use of above "temp=new node"

Comment: @Imposter, it just allocates a new element for the list. For the case `n == NULL` you could simply say `n = new node;` and use `n` throughout that branch of the `if`.

Comment: thanks for the concern.so if i dont write the statement "temp=new node;" and continue with  node *temp in the above code what will be the consequence.